# How to add a custom validation error?

Tags: laravel-4

Here's what I've got:

```
$data = Input::all();
$validator = Validator::make($data, Vehicle::$rules);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

But my `Vehicle::$rules` can't cover all the things I need to validate. How can I add additional error messages into `$validator`?

I've tried

```
$validator->errors()->add("xxx","yyy")
```

But it doesn't seem to actually add an error.

Comment: Do you want to add custom validation rules?

Comment: @smartrahat No. I'll do the validation manually. All I want is to add an extra message. Also, ideally `->fails()` will return true if I've added one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to run additional checks on the date and if it has an error add it to the `withErrors()` method. Here's what I think you are looking for:

```
$errors = [];
$data = Input::all();
$validator = Validator::make($data, Vehicle::$rules);

if($validator->fails()) {
    $errors = $validator->errors()->toArray();
}

// "manual" check
if($data['field'] < 10){
    $errors['field'] = ['My custom error.']
}

if(!empty($errors)){     
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
}
```

Comment: That's more or less what I wanted, but I was hoping I could push the new error message into the $validator object instead of dealing with intermediate array, but if I can't, this will have to do.

Comment: This is what i want , with little modification

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change default validation messages you can do it by editing this file `resources\lang\en\validation.php`

If you want to check the data requested from a form is fit for you application or not you can use if condition. Example: If you want to make username field mandatory (`required` in Laravel validation) your code should look like this in controller-

```
public function store(Request $request){
    if($request['username'] == ''){
        Session::flash('error_message','The username field is required!');
        return redirect('previousPageRoute');
    }

    Session::flash('success_message','Username collected successfully!');
    return redirect('nextPageRoute');
}
```

And your view file should have this to show `session` messages-

```
@if(Session::has('error_message'))
    {{ Session::get('error_message') }}
@if(Session::has('success_message'))
    {{ Session::get('success_message') }}
@endif
```

Comment: I don't want to create a new flash variable. I want to inject a new error message into the `$validator` instance so that it can take advantage of my existing `->fails()` and `Redirect::back()->withErrors` check.